# Posix headers for cross compiling on Windows (specifically for boost)

Tags: linux, boost, clang, llvm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile Boost on Windows to a Linux target using Clang. The compiler is invoking correctly, it seems, but I'm stuck on a missing header file:

#include <pthread.h>

Clang/LLVM doesn't seem to come with its own copies of these posix headers, what's the recommend way for obtaining/setting up these headers for cross compilation?